# set default value of dropdown come from database using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

hey guys i am a biginner in codeigniter,i am working on a application in which i have a edit form,in this form i have a dropdown field,i want to set its value by the value which is already fil in database.i found a solution `set_select` but i dont know how to use it and where in select field pls help . .

my view is . .

```
<td>Moderator :</td>
<td>
    <label for="select"></label>
    <select name="mod" value="" tabindex="1" >
        <?php foreach($dropvalue2 as $value): ?>
        <option value="<?=$value['moderator_id']?>"><?=$value['moderator_name']?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</td>
```

by this i fetch list if dropdown but i want a value at top which is related to row i want to edit  . .

Answer (score 0):

Get the value from the database. Then use it in your loop.

```
foreach($dropvalue2 as $value)
{
    $string = "";
    if($value['moderator_id'] == $moderator_in_db) $string = "SELECTED"; ?>

    <option value="<?= $value['moderator_id'] ?>" <?= $string ?>><?= $value['moderator_name'] ?></option> <?php
}
```

Comment: :- what is string and $moderator_in_db

Comment: I hope I don't have to explain `$string` (it's to switch between adding `SELECTED` or nothing based on conditions) and `$moderator_in_db` is the value in the database you were talking about. And nope, no other ideas.